# Force delete .jar file after closing it (creating Java uninstaller)

Tags: java, windows, jar

I've created Java based uninstaller - but one problem still exists - how can I delete uninstaller .jar file (and related directories - for example .../SomeApplication/uninstaller/uninstaller.jar) after I close it? It is not very nice to leave some files after uninstall..

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this by copying the uninstaller program to a temp folder (`%TEMP%`) with a external utility (bat or sh) and execute the program from that location.

I feel this is a valid implementation because it removes the permanent files and the only file left over will inherently be removed over time or is at least indicated as 'temp'.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this, but if I write to Windows registry key UnistallString 2 commands in one string like (just an example with errors) `cp to %TEMP% directory && ..jawaw.exe -jar UninstallerCopy.jar` - I get the error that file not found (but it was created) - and if I execute the same command again - everything works fine.

Comment: For example - in `IzPack` uninstaller they managed somehow to do that - if checkbox "Force delete..." is checked. Uninstaller is in installed application path.

Comment: Have the user / system execute a batch file which copies the file and then executes the copy. Add error handing to wait a few tries...  I'm not familiar enough with the system aspects of uninstalling, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `File.deleteOnExit()` but it is not quarantined to work on every jvm.
Another option is to write a runner or use a wrapper and add a delete after the java program exits.

**Update**

Example: deinstall.bat

```
java -jar uninstall.jar
REM check exit status of run
delete jar
```

Example: smooth as executable wrapper.
This wrapped uses exitOnDelete and copies the jars to the temp folder.

Comment: No, it's not working.. Runner is not an option also - because executing .jar will not exit till the started another process exit.

Comment: bat file works :) In bat file I've copied with `cp` uninstaller.jar to %TEMP% directory and launched `java -jar %TEMP%\uninstaller.jar`. But one I think big problem - when bat file was launched - console window opened. Is there some option to execute it without console window?

Comment: I think I will try with C++, we'll see later.

Comment: Finally, with C++ application I've managed to achieve desired result. I used `CreateProcessW` to copy uninstall.jar file to %TEMP% directory, then again with `CreateProcessW` started copied file. And I had to add `ExitProcess(0);` at the end of C++ code, to make install.exe not in use. It's a pitty that I can't do it only with Java application.

Comment: .bat file is useless, because to start it without console window it is only possible with `start` option at the beginning of the command line. But in this case - process do not wait while file is copied, and application is started while file is not still created. So C++ - an exe file as a uninstall.jar launcher is acceptable.